# postgres: ensure json column root is an object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm wondering how to ensure that the data inserted into a `json` or `jsonb` column is an object, not an array (or an array of objects).

Example:

```
-- ok
insert into users (settings) values ('{ "theme": "cobalt" }')

-- ok
insert into users (settings) values ('{}')

-- error!
insert into users (settings) values ('[]')

-- error!
insert into users (settings) values ('[{}]')
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can have a check constraint to check the first symbol not to be `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do [smth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) like:

```
t=# create table so16(j jsonb check (left(ltrim(j::text), 1) <> '['));
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so16 values('{"b":[1,2,3]}');
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so16 values('[1,2,3]');
ERROR:  new row for relation "so16" violates check constraint "so16_j_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ([1, 2, 3]).
t=# insert into so16 values('   [1,2,3]');
ERROR:  new row for relation "so16" violates check constraint "so16_j_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ([1, 2, 3]).
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better way, but it seems like this is the way to go – thanks!